# How to compute average colours of the edges of a composite tv signal

Tags: avr, pic, video

I want to create something like ambilight that can work based on a composite tv input.

Basically I need to work out the average colour and brightness at 3 or 4 points along each edge which can then be used to control strips of RGB leds.

I have no problem with the LED control part but where do I start with dealing with the TV signal?  Can anyone point me in the right direction of what component I could use or where to learn how to do this with a PIC?

Answer (score 1):

I think an analog solution is the best. A hybrid digital-analog solution will be tricky, but not impossible.

Have a look at the chips used in a CRT TV. You may be able to hack one to get R, G, B outputs. To take the edge colours only might require storing the frame and grabbing pixels. It could be tricky, in other words.

Answer (score 1):

This might be easier with an RGB signal (as found in VGA and sometimes carried by SCART). With that, you could probably watch VSYNC with an interrupt, then sample the R/G/B lines and produce your colour.

But, for composite you're going to have to pick apart the [colourburst](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorburst). To do this, you'll need a fast clock. It won't be easy with a PIC.

Comment: The only problem that could be with this is that SCART doesn't always provide RGB. Sometimes it's just composite, sometimes it's even Y/Cb/Cr. But an ambilight with VGA would be pretty easy - just sample at each VSYNC change. With composite you'd need to sync to the colorburst then decode the amplitude and phase of the signal (encoding the two colour components.)